# Elastic (v6.4) aggregation: is it possible to return buckets for documents that are requested but aren't found?

Tags: elasticsearch

The purpose of this query is to aggregate how many documents of the specified document type each division of the specified leading division has.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "division.leadingDivisionId": "554"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms": {
                        "documentType.id": [
                            "72"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "registrationNumber"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "body": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "division.leadingDivisionId",
                "size": 1500,
                "order": {
                    "_count": "desc"
                },
                "min_doc_count": 1
            },
            "aggs": {
                "body": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "division.id",
                        "size": 1500,
                        "order": {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        },
                        "min_doc_count": 1
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "body": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "documentType.id",
                                "size": 1500,
                                "order": {
                                    "_term": "asc"
                                },
                                "min_doc_count": 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The issue with this query is that when no documents of the specified type exist in the division, a bucket like this isn't returned:

```
{
  "Key": "72",
  "doc_count": 0,
  "key_as_string": null,
  "Body": null
}
```

It is only returned when at least some documents exist, but do not correspond the criteria of having a registration number, for example.

Is it possible to get the bucket even in this case, when no such documents exist? The goal is to get the same amount and order of buckets for each division.

Comment: set `min_doc_count` to `0` for all the parent level aggregation and check.

Comment: I set all to 0 and only get extra divisions. Setting only the first one (for `"field": "division.leadingDivisionId",`) didn't seem to do anything at all.

Comment: Yes, because you are using parent and sub level aggregation. so you need to set it for all the aggregation to 0 then only you will get.

Comment: Can you please write an answer with the exact place where it should be put? I tried to place another `min_doc_count` in various places, but I either get errors or unexpected results.

Comment: In your current query itself, you need to put min_doc_count 0 for all 3 aggregation.

Comment: As I already wrote, that does not work. I read that for Elastic it is impossible to return such nonexisting results in this way, and filtering has to be used instead.